# The 'plan_image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django

I want to serialize Construction object in EventSerializer (method get_construction)
But i have sophisticated relation between Event and Construction

Wheh I perform request http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/

I have an error

> The 'plan_image' attribute has no file associated with it.

How can I fix this error?
I a using model_to_dict from django.forms.models  and I think that problem deals with this method

**models.py**

```
class Construction(models.Model):
        """ Объект строительства"""
        developer = models.ForeignKey(
            Developer, related_name="constructions", on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        plan_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=name_image, blank=True, null=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        coordinates = models.PointField(blank=True)
        deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, )
        workers_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        machines_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class Zone(models.Model):
        construction = models.ForeignKey(
            Construction, related_name="zones", on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
        time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        points = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    
    
    class Camera(models.Model):
        building = models.ForeignKey(
            Construction, related_name="cameras", on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        proc_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        path_frames = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
        zone_id_x = models.IntegerField(default=-1) # -1 means that zone is not set
        zone_id_y = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        def set_proc_id(self):
            """ Set process id for a new camera"""
            self.proc_id = 12
            self.save()
    
        def set_path_frame(self):
            """ Set path to folders with photos"""
            self.path_frames = f"/photos/camera/{self.id}/"
            self.save()
    
    
    class Frame(models.Model):
        """ Фото с камеры """
        camera_id = models.ForeignKey(
            Camera, related_name="frames", on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        url_to_frame = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.timestamp}_{self.url_to_frame}"
    
    
    class Event(models.Model):
        """ Событие с камеры """
        EVENT_TYPES = (
            (EVENTS[0], "worker_detected"),
            (EVENTS[1], "machine_detected"),
            (EVENTS[2], "fire_detected"),
            (EVENTS[3], "worker_no_helmet"),
            (EVENTS[4], "worker_no_vest"),
            (EVENTS[5], "new_machine"),
            (EVENTS[6], "other_event")
        )
    
        OBJECT_TYPES = (
            (OBJECTS[0], "worker"),
            (OBJECTS[1], "machine"),
            (OBJECTS[2], "building")
        )
    
        frame_id = models.ForeignKey(
            Frame, related_name="events", on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
        type_of_event = models.CharField(
            choices=EVENT_TYPES, max_length=20, default=EVENTS[0],
        )
        class_name = models.CharField(
            choices=OBJECT_TYPES, max_length=20, default=OBJECTS[0],
        )
        grn = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
        track_id = models.IntegerField()  # e.g id of worker or machibe
        bounding_coords = models.CharField(max_length=16)  # format "111_111_111_111"
        time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.type_of_event}_{self.class_name}_{self.time}"
        
        def json(self):
            """ Convrt object to json"""
            res = {}
            res["frame_id"] = self.frame_id.pk
            res["type_of_event"] = self.type_of_event
            res["class_name"] = self.class_name
            res["grn"] = self.grn
            res["track_id"] = self.track_id
            res["bounding_coords"] = self.bounding_coords
            res["time"] = self.time
    
            return res
```

**serializers.py**

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time = serializers.DateTimeField(format=TIME_FORMAT)
    camera = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    construction = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            'id', 'frame_id', 'camera', 'construction', 'type_of_event', 'class_name',
            'grn', 'track_id', 'bounding_coords', 'time'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super().create(validated_data=validated_data)
        return instance
    
    def get_camera(self, obj):
        return model_to_dict(obj.frame_id.camera_id)
    
    def get_construction(self, obj):
        return model_to_dict(obj.frame_id.camera_id.building)
```

Full error text

```
Internal Server Error: /api/events/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/render.py", line 17, in render
    camelize(data, **api_settings.JSON_UNDERSCOREIZE), *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 46, in camelize
    return [camelize(item, **options) for item in data]
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 46, in <listcomp>
    return [camelize(item, **options) for item in data]
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 41, in camelize
    new_dict[new_key] = camelize(value, **options)
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 41, in camelize
    new_dict[new_key] = camelize(value, **options)
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 46, in camelize
    return [camelize(item, **options) for item in data]
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 46, in <listcomp>
    return [camelize(item, **options) for item in data]
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 78, in __iter__
    for chunk in self.chunks():
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 55, in chunks
    self.seek(0)
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    seek = property(lambda self: self.file.seek)
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 43, in _get_file
    self._require_file()
  File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/38_safe_building/1_code/buildings/back/api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 40, in _require_file
    raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)
ValueError: The 'plan_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace? You need to check that a file has been added before trying to access the file when you see an error like this.

Comment: @markwalker_ added full error text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this function, you'll need to use `exclude` when your file field hasn't been set (because it's optional/`blank=True`)

```
def model_to_dict(instance, fields=None, exclude=None):
    """
    Return a dict containing the data in ``instance`` suitable for passing as
    a Form's ``initial`` keyword argument.

    ``fields`` is an optional list of field names. If provided, return only the
    named.

    ``exclude`` is an optional list of field names. If provided, exclude the
    named from the returned dict, even if they are listed in the ``fields``
    argument.
    """
```

You'll need to do your check similar to this;

```py
    def get_construction(self, obj):
        if obj.frame.camera.building.plan_image:
            # plan_image exists
            return model_to_dict(obj.frame_id.camera_id.building)
        else:
            # plan_image doesn't exist so exclude
            return model_to_dict(
                obj.frame_id.camera_id.building
                exclude=['plan_image', ]
            )
```

On a related note, where you use a `ForeignKey` in a model, django will add a suffix of `_id` to the database field, so typically people don't add that suffix to the model field as well.